# Coverting Hex to ASCII Characters in Python

Tags: python, data-conversion

I want to get something that looks like this:

```
Kì°k[7ì]ÿ¯G]ìw/uëGU—kÔÍj+³¯Mè1Sjwˆ½öm�Á|Uç
```

But instead I keep getting this when using
binascii.unhexlify(ph) #ph is a Hex_string:

```
x05\x00\x00\xd0\x05\x00data!W\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\
```

PS: I'm basically trying to convert an AUDIO file to another extension by removing some line of codes from a string i made which contains Hex values. (I tried it manually with Hex Editor and it works just fine, i wanted to make a python script for it but i found an impass in the conversion step)

[Here is an example of what i want to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cso3B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is having the same question i found out what the answer is. Let's say i want to convert the ch="E4BC716838B15CE6FCD5" Hex string to ASCII and ph is the ascii string i want to get:
Simply loop over the string two characters at a time, use int() over those two strings along with 16 then use chr() to convert the number into a character.
Here's the code:

```
ch="E4BC716838B15CE6FCD5"
ph=''
for i in range(1,(len(ch)//2)+1):
   Lh=''                 
   Lh=ch[2*i-2:2*i]              #This is the two char string for each loop
   x = int(Lh,16)                #The value of the 'Lh' Hex
   ph=ph+chr(x)                  #chr is used to convert the int to ascii
```

The result is ph='ä¼qh8±\æüÕ'